# CodeIgniter's default controller doesn't load

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have inherited an on-going CI v2.0.2 project.

I tried loading the default controller - `http://localhost/ci202/index.php` - but all I got was a blank page.

I enabled logging for all messages, and here's the log:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
```

To get this log, I only re-loaded `index.php` once.

The contents of `routes.php` & `.htaccess` are the same as the default installation of CI v2.0.2.

I tried creating another 'helloworld' type controller, which was a replica of the welcome controller, but still get a blank page.

Where else should I look for misconfiguration?

Comment: sounds like you are getting a white screen of death? have you tried using a completely blank installation of codeigniter on your server - confirmed that is working ok?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Yes, a completely new installation of CI v.2.0.2 works perfect on my machine.

Comment: You should check your error log from Apache - sounds like PHP is failing and not CI.

Comment: Try to rename the index.php to something like `home.php`. One more thing you can do is go to `/config/routes.php` and change `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';` to another controller.

Comment: any solution on this? 
I have the same error. Going mad with this white screen of death. (haha Shift Exchange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you to find the problem.

1. Make sure the database connection is successful
2. If you enabled output compression from CI config file, disable it from `config.php`:

   `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;`
3. Change the default environment setting from `index.php to` development`, so you can see any errors that may occur in the application:

   `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`